# scanf not working in multithreads

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I want to create a multi client handling server. It has 1 thread to handle all the clients but the scanf function is not working and the while loop keeps on going.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define PORT 80
int totalclient = 0;
int clientsocket[100];

void error_message(char *m)
{
  printf("%s", m);
  exit(1);
}

void *multi_clients()
{
  int c1;

  while(1)
    printf("Server is running, enter your option for clients\n");
    scanf(" %d", &c1); // here scanf is not working.

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t Thread;
  int sock, valread, valthread;
  struct sockaddr_in saddr;
  int addrlen = sizeof(saddr);
  int opt = 1;
  char buffer[] = "hello";
  int temp=0;

  if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    error_message("socket cannot be created\n");

  if((setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,
        &opt, sizeof(opt))))
        error_message("setsocket");

  saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  saddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

  if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, addrlen) <0)
    error_message("bind failed\n");

  if(listen(sock, 3) < 0)
    error_message("listen");

  if((valthread = pthread_create(&Thread, NULL, multi_clients,
                                  NULL)))
       error_message("thread\n");

  printf("accepting connection....\n");

  while(1)
  {
    if((clientsocket[totalclient] = accept(sock,
        (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) <0)
        printf("error accepting connection\n");
    else
      send(clientsocket[totalclient], buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
      totalclient++;
  }

  return 0;

}
```

is their any other better option to take input from user in multi threading.

Comment: are you trying to read from a socket? `scanf()` reads `stdin`! You could try `fscanf()` but it would probably be a bad idea, use `recv()`, `read()` or maybe even `fgets()` after an `fdopen()`. And then, there's a function returning a pointer per declaration, but it doesn't return anything. And probably a lot of other weirdness. I strongly suggest you start small, piece by piece ...

Comment: Your `scanf()` is not part of the `while` loop. The loop is endless printing. You forgot the brackets.

Comment: If your compiler did not issue any warnings for this code, you need to get a standard compliant compiler.

Comment: Also note that 'void *multi_clients()' is an incorrect signature for a pthreads thread function.

Comment: `scanf` is not into the while-loop. Only `printf` is into the while-loop. On the other hand I suspect that scanf and printf are not thread-safe, then, if you runs more thread instances of the function `void *multi_clients()`, you have to manage mutex ... But using mutex I suspect you cannot have a real multi-thread result if you use scanf!

Comment: the actual question is not answered yet. Why Scanf is not  working